# DateDiff produces incorrect result when I set the dd value to 12 or less. The format of the date is mm/dd/yy

Tags: excel, vba

If the "dd" value of the date is "12" or less, on the StartDate variable, then the answer is incorrect.

Eg. When the StartDate is "03/12/19" and the EndDate value is "03/23/19", it yields -5573, which is obviously the incorrect answer.

If the "dd" value of the date is "13" or more, on the StartDate variable, then the answer is correct.

Eg When the StartDate is "03/13/19" and the EndDate value is "03/23/19", it yields 10, which is the correct answer.

I don't quite understand.
BTW the vba code is on a MacOS Excel Mac 2011.

Also, the weird thing is that this exact same workbook code works perfectly on my Win 7 PC Excel 2007 regardless of what value of the "dd" you use.!!!!

```vb
Sub DateDiffTest()

    Dim StartDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim EndDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim Msg
    StartDate = Format("03/12/19", "mm-dd-yy")
    EndDate = Format("03/23/19", "mm-dd-yy")
    Msg = "Days from today: " & DateDiff("d", EndDate, StartDate)
    MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Comment: Please take any cell on your excel sheet and put now() and see in what format date is coming ie `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` etc . Same format fo date should be used in your code and format pattern. However your code interprets correct values in my `Excel 2016 Windows 10` as locals date setting here is `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Comment: I'm not using either dates on my spreadsheet. I use the result to determine what action I will take further on in my macro (which I am not showing in this example). I'm actually just using the sample code to illustrate the problem with not coming up with the right result depending on what "dd" value I use in the DateDiff function. Even using the Format function doesn't seem to make a difference. This is only a snippet of a larger macro that works perfectly on my Win 7 Excel 2007 to highlight the problem I get when I use a "dd" value less than thirteen. Weird!!!

Comment: Essentially, the DateDiff works perfectly on my Win 7 PC Excel 2007 with any value in the "dd" position and only if the value of "dd" is 13 or greater on my Mac Excel 2011.

Comment: Dates are entered as date literals to remove locale from coercion. `#12/6/2019#`. means 6th December. `msgbox FormatDateTime(#12/6/2019#, 1)`. This is well known and nothing weird about it. This is the underlying COM function that does it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-vardatefromstr

Comment: All source code is US English. When you put a date into a string it's not source code and will be interpreted according to the locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems have to do with undeclared variables, and with VBA being US-Centric in its use of dates and with your Regional settings being inconsistent with what you are doing.

I suspect your Regional short date settings are YMD.

And what you think is `dd`, VBA thinks is `mm`.

So when the value is `<= 12` it converts it to `YMD`
  `StartDate --> 2003-Dec-19`

When it is `>12`, it cannot be a month, so VBA interprets it as a day, and converts it as a US-Centric date.  So `EndDate --> 2019-Mar-23`

You should declare all variables, and also, when coding, use unambiguous dates.

eg:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DateDiffTest()
    'OK to use US-centric MDY here
    Const StartDate As Date = #3/12/2019#
    Const EndDate As Date = #3/23/2019#
    Dim Msg As String

Msg = "Days from today: " & DateDiff("d", EndDate, StartDate)
MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Another method of unambiguously declaring the dates:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DateDiffTest()
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim Msg As String

StartDate = "2019-Mar-12"
EndDate = "2019-Mar-23"

Msg = "Days from today: " & DateDiff("d", EndDate, StartDate)
MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

By the way, I don't understand why MS makes NOT requiring variable declaration the default. Select `Tools/Options/Editor` and check `Require Variable Declaration`.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of any new module.  To correct **this** module, enter it manually at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent insight. However, the StartDate variable is getting it's value from a file that I read in that is in the format "mm/dd/yy". Therefore I don't have any way of changing that value into the format that you are suggesting. Or is there any easy little piece of code that you can suggest to convert it into the format you use in your example #3/12/2019#.

Comment: It depends on how you are reading in the file, type of file, etc. That's a different issue, but usually easily solved.

Comment: Thank you Ron Rosenfeld. I did however look at my short date settings on my Mac and  changed them to match the format of the dates I'm reading in, and it now seems to work correctly! Thank you so much for that excellent suggestion!!

Comment: If you `A = split("12/31/2019", "/")` you will get a three element array with `x(0)` = 12. `y=CDate(x(1) & "/" & x(0) & "/" & x(2))`

Comment: @Noodles That won't work reliably under the particular circumstances `OPEN`ing a text file with a mismatch in the date format compared with the Windows regional format), since Excel will have already messed up the date translation.  And if measures are taken so Excel doesn't mess it up, then it is unnecessary.